# Google Appmaker supported Drive API Version

Tags: google-drive-api, google-app-maker

I have a python script running with Drive v3 and i was playing around with the Google AppMaker tool, I am actually running the advanced services on it which I just found out it runs on v2 (?!) which breaks my previous setup. Do you know if there's any possibility to run it on v3 somehow?

Comment: Yes there is. You'll have to use the [REST api](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/)  with the [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) class.

Comment: That could be a solution but our problem is that, in App Maker, we can't easily embed any json credentials file when using REST API, with the embedded 'Drive' functionality in App Maker the permissions are directly from the developer which make it easier.

Comment: You can always use service accounts and impersonate users. Not sure what you are trying to achieve but good luck!

Comment: I think we are good in the end running on version 2 in App Maker, I have modified our python script to run in that version as I think it was the quickest modification... thanks @Morfinismo anyway :)